# How to force a certain groups of targets to be always run sequentially?

Tags: parallel-processing, makefile, gnu-make, ghc

Is there a way how to ask gmake to never run two targets from a set in parallel?

I don't want to use .NOTPARALLEL, because it forces the whole Makefile to be run sequentially, not just the required part.

I could also add dependencies so that one depends on another, but then (apart from being ugly) I'd need to build all of them in order to build the last one, which isn't necessary.

---

The reason why I need this is that (only a) part of my Makefile invokes `ghc --make`, which takes care of its dependencies itself. And it's not possible to run it in parallel on two different targets, because if the two targets share some dependency, they can rewrite each other's `.o` file. (But `ghc` is fine with being called sequentially.)

**Update:** To give a specific example. Let's say I need to compile two programs in my Makefile:

- `prog1` depends on `prog1.hs` and `mylib.hs`;
- `prog2` depends on `prog2.hs` and `mylib.hs`.

Now if I invoke [`ghc --make prog1.hs`](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/), it checks its dependencies, compiles both `prog1.hs` and `mylib.hs` into their respective object and interface files, and links `prog1`. The same happens when I call `ghc --make prog2.hs`. So if they the two commands get to run in parallel, one will overwrite `mylib.o` of the other one, causing it to fail badly.

However, I need that neither `prog1` depends on `prog2` nor vice versa, because they should be compilable separately. (In reality they're very large with a lot of modules and requiring to compile them all slows development considerably.)

Answer (score 10):

Hmmm, could do with a bit more information, so this is just a stab in the dark.

Make doesn't really support this, but you can sequential-ise two targets in a couple of ways. First off, a real use for recursive make:

```
targ1: ; recipe1...
targ2: ; recipe2...

both-targets:
    ${MAKE} targ1
    ${MAKE} targ2
```

So here you can just `make -j both-targets` and all is fine. Fragile though, because `make -j targ1 targ2` still runs in parallel. You can use dependencies instead:

```
targ1: ; recipe1...
targ2: | targ1 ; recipe2...
```

Now `make -j targ1 targ2` does what you want. Disadvantage? `make targ2` will always try to build `targ1` first (sequentially). This may (or may not) be a show-stopper for you.

### EDIT

Another unsatisfactory strategy is to explicitly look at `$MAKECMDGOALS`, which lists the targets you specified on the command-line. Still a fragile solution as it is broken when someone uses dependencies inside the *Makefile* to get things built (a not unreasonable action).

Let's say your makefile contains two independent targets `targ1` and `targ2`. Basically they remain independent until someone specifies on the command-line that they must *both* be built. In this particular case you break this independence. Consider this snippet:

```
$(and $(filter targ1,${MAKECMDGOALS)),$(filter targ2,${MAKECMDGOALS}),$(eval targ1: | targ2))
```

Urk! What's going on here?

- Make evaluates the `$(and)`
- It first has to expand `$(filter targ1,${MAKECMDGOALS})`
- Iff `targ1` *was* specified, it goes on to expand `$(filter targ2,${MAKECMDGOALS})`
- Iff `targ2` was *also* specified, it goes on to expand the `$(eval)`, forcing the serialization of `targ1` and `targ2`.

  - Note that the `$(eval)` expands to nothing (all its work was done as a side-effect), so that the original `$(and)` always expands to nothing at all, causing no syntax error.

Ugh!

[Now that I've typed that out, the considerably simpler `prog2: | $(filter prog1,${MAKECMDGOALS})`
occurs to me. Oh well.]

YMMV and all that.

I'm not familiar with *ghc*, but the correct solution would be to get the two runs of ghc to use different build folders, then they can happily run in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. Neither one solves my problem in the way I'd need, but still they're valuable. I updated my question with a more specific example, perhaps it'll help.

Comment: The | (pipeline) character forces execution by order

See section 4.3 in the manual at:

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile

Comment: @shloma Yeah, see my earlier comment after the "Ugh!" It makes hardly any difference to the problems above though. Particularly if `targ2` is `.PHONY`

Answer (score 5):

Since I got stuck at the same problem, here is another pointer in the direction that `make` does not provide the functionality you describe:

From the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Archive-Pitfalls.html#Archive-Pitfalls):

> It is important to be careful when using parallel execution (the -j switch; see Parallel Execution) and archives. If multiple ar commands run at the same time on the same archive file, they will not know about each other and can corrupt the file.
>
> Possibly a future version of make will provide a mechanism to circumvent this problem by serializing all recipes that operate on the same archive file. But for the time being, you must either write your makefiles to avoid this problem in some other way, or not use -j.

What you are attempting, and what I was attempting (using make to insert data in a SQLite3 database) suffers from the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to separate the compilation from other steps (cleaning, building dirs and linking), as I wanted to run the compilation with more core processes and the -j flag.

I managed to solve this, with different makefiles including and calling each other. Only the "compile" make file is running in parallel with all the cores, the rest of the process is syncronous.

I divided my makefile in 3 separate scripts:

- **settings.mk**: contains all the variables and flag definitions
- **makefile**: has all the targets except the compilation one (It has .NOTPARALLEL directive). It calls compile.mk with -j flag
- **compile.mk**: contains only the compile operation (without .NOTPARALLEL)

In **settings.mk** I have:

```
CC = g++
DB = gdb
RM = rm
MD = mkdir
CP = cp
MAKE = mingw32-make
BUILD = Debug
DEBUG = true

[... all other variables and flags needed, directories etc ...]
```

In **makefile** I have Link and compilation target as these:

```
include .makefiles/settings.mk

[... OTHER TARGETS (clean, directories etc)]

compilation:
    @echo Compilation
    @$(MAKE) -f .makefiles/compile.mk --silent -j 8 -Oline

#Link
$(TARGET): compilation
    @echo -e Linking $(TARGET)
    @$(CC) $(LNKFLAGS) -o $(TARGETDIR)/$(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBDIRS) $(LIB)

#Non-File Targets
.PHONY: all prebuild release rebuild clean resources directories run debug

.NOTPARALLEL: all

 # include dependency files (*.d) if available
 -include $(DEPENDS)
```

And this is my **compile.mk**:

```
include .makefiles/settings.mk

#Defauilt
all: $(OBJECTS)

#Compile
$(BUILDDIR)/%.$(OBJEXT): $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @echo -e Compiling: $<
    @$(MD) -p $(dir $@)
    @$(CC) $(COMFLAGS) $(INCDIRS) -c $< -o $@

#Non-File Targets
.PHONY: all

# include dependency files (*.d) if available
-include $(DEPENDS)
```

Until now, it's working.

Note that I'm calling compile.mk with -j flag AND -Oline so that parallel processing doesn't mess up with the output.

Any syntax color can be setted in the makefile main script, since the -O flag invalidates escape color codes.

I hope it can help.

Comment: `.NOTPARALLEL` ignores its targets, so `.NOTPARALLEL: all` is the same as `.NOTPARALLEL:`, meaning that *no* targets in the Makefile are allowed to be parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your case, you could try `.WAIT` between target's dependencies, check it here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Disable.html. That would require recent version of make == 4.4 (https://lwn.net/Articles/913253/)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem so ended up solving it on the command line, like so:

`make target1; make target2`

to force it to do the targets sequentially.